# How to draw contour line between certain elevation range?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, contour

I have a raster and I want to draw contour lines just between certain elevation range.
For example I want to draw contour lines between elevation 700 (m) and 1000 (m) with the interval of 10. So there must be 30 contour lines. I use ArcGIS. Do you have any idea what tool I should use to make it work?

Comment: Since you intend to compare contours between datasets, you might be interested in the related thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55507, which asks "I am looking for a way to spatially quantify the difference between three contour line shapefiles." If you have the original raster data, though, then forget about the contours: compare the rasters directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have the **[Spatial Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcGIS_Spatial_Analyst_extension/005900000001000000/)** or [**3D Analyst**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcGIS_3D_Analyst_extension/00q8000000wv000000/) extension installed, you can use the **[Contour tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000ts000000)**.  This allows you to set an interval as you require.  This will create contours over your whole raster.  Then you can easily select those between 700 and 1000 using **[Select By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly I've tried that way. Actually my main goal is that I want to compare contour lines of some raster types so I need the contour lines at exact elevations. ArcMap provides ContourList tool to do that, but then I have to insert the elevations where I want to create contour lines at. It's really time consuming. I'd like to find faster way to do that :)

Comment: if you know some python you can try to make a script to do it for you, and save some time (or at least automatice the process).

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to GIS and I know none of python. Maybe I'll try learn some of it. Thanks.